# Is there a way to create a combination using nested loops?

Tags: python, nested-loops

I'm new to python and am learning about nested loops. I'm aiming to create a code to list every combination given variables. My code currently doesn't work and I can't figure out why. I'm testing this variation   howmanycombos(1,1,1). Which returns ['0,0,0'] when it should return ['0,0,0', '0,0,1', '0,1,0', '0,1,1', '1,0,0', '1,0,1', '1,1,0', '1,1,1']

Wonder if anyone can help me understand :)

```
def howmanycombos(l1,l2,l3):
    newlist = []
    for i in range(l1):
        for j in range(l2):
            for k in range(l3):
                newlist.append('{},{},{}'.format(i,j,k))
    return newlist
```

Answer (score 2):

In [`range(stop)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) `stop` is actually exclusive, so `range(1)` will give just a `[0]`.

Call it with `howmanycombos(2,2,2)` and you'll get

```
['0,0,0', '0,0,1', '0,1,0', '0,1,1', '1,0,0', '1,0,1', '1,1,0', '1,1,1']
```